# How to handle or detect when a maze has no solution?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, maze

I am trying to make maze solver in python.

The parameters are as follows

y (int): Start location of y

x (int): Start location of x

The starting point is (y,x), The coordinates for the left-top, left-bottom, right-top, and right-bottom are (0,0), (N,0), (0,N), (N,N), respectively, for the maze map of size N by N.

The search function return (bool): If maze has solution or not, return True or False respectively.

The solve function returns nothing: Print out a single path solution.

I have managed to write the code and get solutions for the maze, but I have a problem when the maze has no solution. It does not stop and just goes on running infinite loops.

Below is my code

```
class Maze():
    def __init__(self, grid):

        self.grid = grid

    def search(self, y, x):

        self.y = y
        self.x = x

        if x == len(self.grid[0]) or y == len(self.grid):
            print('out of maze')
            return False
        if self.grid[y][x] == 'F':
            self.cleanup()
            return True
        if self.grid[y][x] != 'o' and self.grid[y][x] != ' ':
            print('ran into a wall')
            return False

        self.grid[y][x] = ' '

        if x <= len(self.grid[0])-2:
            if self.grid[y][x+1] == 'o' or self.grid[y][x+1] == 'F':
                print(x,y)
                return self.search(y,x+1)
        if y <= len(self.grid)-2:
            if self.grid[y+1][x] == 'o' or self.grid[y+1][x] == 'F':
                print(x,y)
                return self.search(y+1,x)
        if x > 1:
            if self.grid[y][x-1] == 'o' or self.grid[y][x-1] == 'F':
                print(x,y)
                return self.search(y,x-1)
        if y > 1:
            if self.grid[y-1][x] == 'o' or self.grid[y-1][x] == 'F':
                print(x,y)
                return self.search(y-1,x) 


        if x > 1:
            if self.grid[y][x-1] == ' ' or self.grid[y][x-1] == 'F':
                print(x,y)
                return self.search(y,x-1)
        if y > 1:
            if self.grid[y-1][x] == ' ' or self.grid[y-1][x] == 'F':
                print(x,y)
                return self.search(y-1,x)
        if x <= len(self.grid[0])-2:
            if self.grid[y][x+1] == ' ' or self.grid[y][x+1] == 'F':
                print(x,y)
                return self.search(y,x+1)
        if y <= len(self.grid)-2:
            if self.grid[y+1][x] == ' ' or self.grid[y+1][x] == 'F':
                print(x,y)
                return self.search(y+1,x)

        print("can't find a way")
        return False

    def cleanup(self):
        for r in range(len(self.grid)):
            for c in range(len(self.grid[0])):
                if self.grid[r][c] == ' ':
                    self.grid[r][c] = 'o'

    def solve(self, y, x):

        if self.search(y, x):
            print("Solution")
            ### CODE HERE ###
        else:
            print('There are NO solutions')
```

This is my main

```
for i, maze_map in enumerate(maze_map_list):  
    maze = Maze(maze_map)
    print(i+1, '-1')
    maze.solve(0,0)
    print(i+1, '-2')
    maze.solve(4,0)
    print()
```

and this is the grid that I am unable to work on

```
.
.
grid2 = ['o o o o o o'.split(' '),
         '+ + o + + +'.split(' '),
         'F + o o o o'.split(' '),
         'o o + + + o'.split(' '),
         'o o o + + o'.split(' ')] 
.
.
.
maze_map_list = [grid1, grid2, grid3, grid4]
```

Comment: To make sure I understand, `' '` represents a position that was already tried, and `'o'` represents open space that hasn't been tried yet?

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill help?

Comment: If `search()` returns `False` don't call `solve()`. On the other hand, if it returns `True` then the solution can be found in a way very similar to how `search()` determined one existed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes you are right! I will try to understand the wiki page.

Comment: @martineau I don't quite understand. So do you mean I should not call search in the solve function?

Comment: I meant if `search()` indicates there's no solution, don't call `solve()` to get it — and if it does indicate there is one, then however `search()` determined that one existed would be _very_ similar to what `solve()` should do print it out.